# Template deduction seems wrong

Tags: c++, templates

Template deduced seemed wrong, why (c) is called rather than (b)?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T> void f(T){cout << "f(T)";}//(a)
template<> void f<>(int*){cout << "f(int*)";}//(b)
template<class T> void f(T*){cout << "f(T*)";}//(c)
//void f(int*){cout <<"POD:f(int*)";}//(d)

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    int p = 1;
    f(&p);
    cout <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

> `f(T*)`

Comment: See [why not specialize function templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: @jogojapan I changed the title of the duplicate to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's set straight what we have first.

(a) is a function template. (b) is a specialization of that function template. (c) is another function template that overloads (a).

When you write `f(&p)` there are two overloads to consider: the two function templates, (a) and (c). In (c) `T*` is more specialized than `T` in (a), so (c) gets picked.

Now let's consider the commented out (d). This is not a specialization of the function template (a), but an additional overload. To resolve the `f(&p)` call, there are now three overloads to consider. (d) is not a template and has `int*` matching the type of `&p`, so it gets picked over the other two.

Comment: (bx) has already been in code named (d) :)

Comment: @yuan oh. My eyes just read past the commented code. Dammit, they're too well trained :(

Answer (score 0):

Template specialization must come after the template.
Here, in your case, it looks like this:

```
template<class T> void f(T){cout << "f(T)";}//(a) // Template 1
template<> void f<>(int*){cout << "f(int*)";}//(b) // Specialization of template 1
template<class T> void f(T*){cout << "f(T*)";}//(c) // Template 2, conceals template 1
```

Hence, you get template 2 instantiated.
Correct way toi do it is:

```
template<class T> void f(T*){cout << "f(T*)";} // Template 1
template<class T> void f(T){cout << "f(T)";} // Template 2
template<> void f<>(int*){cout << "f(int*)";} // Specialization of the template 1
```

output:

```
f(int*)
```